# Find a relationship between the probability of at least $k$ events occurring and exactly $k$ and $k+1$ events occuring

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A_{1}, A_{2},...,A_{n}$ be events. Define $P(B_{k})$ to be the probability that at least $k$ of the events $A$ occur. Define $P(C_{k})$ to be the probability that exactly $k$ of the events $A$ occur. Write $P(B_{k})$ in terms of $P(C_{k})$ and $P(C_{k+1})$.

Attempt:

On the one hand we have $$P(B_{k}) = 1 - (P(C_{0}) + P(C_{1}) + ... + P(C_{k-1})).$$ Equivalently, $$P(B_{k}) = P(C_{k}) + ... + P(C_{n}) = P(C_{k}) + P(C_{k+1}) + P(B_{k+2})$$

Any hints?

Comment: Without the added information that all the $A_i$ are independent (occurrence is uncorrelated) the problem as posed cannot be solved.  [Technically, other extra information would also do, but I'm convinced the actual problem said something about independence.]

Comment: @MarkFischler 

#44. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwLxA8Gxlom_S1dJazgwMHJmSW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarkFischler said, the problem is not possible as stated. Consider the following Venn diagram, where blank entries indicate probabilities of $0$:
[image]

In both diagrams, $P(C_1) = P(C_2) = 0$. However, in the top diagram, $P(B_1) = 0.1$, and in the bottom one, $P(B_1) = 0$. Therefore, $P(B_1)$ is not expressible as a function of $P(C_1)$ and $P(C_2)$.

I suspect that the author intended for $P(C_k)$ to be expressed as a function of $P(B_k)$ and $P(B_{k+1})$ instead of what was written.

Comment: Beautiful example. Thank you.